# How I match two email address in codeigniter with help of jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

HTML Page- Hii, I am Keshav Bhatt. 
I,am adding the match two email address validation in my form with jQuery validation in CI. I,am not getting error my data passes through AJAX but two email match validation is not working in client side. below HTML code my JQuery code is. What mistake am I doing?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="eng">
<html>
<?php
if (isset($this->session->userdata['logged_in'])) {
    //header("location: http://localhost/ci/Form/user_login_process");
}
?>
<head>
<title>Registration</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url();?>assets\css\style.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="<--?php echo $this->base_url();?>assets/js/validation.js"></script>
</head>    
<body style="background-color:rgb(90,90,90);color:white  " >
<form id="reg_form"  class="form-horizontal">    
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="col-sm-2"></div>    
<div class="col-sm-8" style="background-color:white; margin-top: 120px; border-radius:20px;">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info" style="margin-left:955px; margin-top:-200px;" onclick="location.href='http://localhost/ci/form/fetch'">Dash Board</button>    
<h2><legend style="color:#678;"><center>Enter Your Details Here</center><span class="req" >required *</span></legend></h2>    
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="username" class="control-label col-sm-2" ><span class="req">*</span>Username</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
            <input type="text" name="username" id="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter User Name"/>
        </div>
        <span class="error"><?php echo form_error('username'); ?></span>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="password" class="control-label col-sm-2"><span class="req">*</span>Password</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
            <input type="password"  name="password" id="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter User Password"/>
        </div>
        <span class="error"><?php echo form_error('password'); ?></span>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
<label for="passconf" class="control-label col-sm-2"><span class="req">*</span>ConfirmPassword</label>
<div class="col-sm-10">
<div class="input-group">
<span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
<input type="password"  name="passconf" id="passconf" class="form-control"  placeholder="Confirm Users Password"/>
</div>
<span class="error"<?php echo form_error('passconf'); ?></span>
</div>
</div>    
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="email" class="control-label col-sm-2"><span class="req">* </span>Email</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
            <input type="text" name="email" id="email" class="form-control" placeholder="someone@example.com"/>
        </div>
        <span class="error"><?php echo form_error('email'); ?><span>
    </div>
</div>
</br>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="emailconf" class="control-label col-sm-2"><span class="req">* </span>ConfirmEmail</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
            <input type="text" name="emailconf" id="emailconf" class="form-control" placeholder="someone@example.com"/>
        </div>
        <span class="error"><?php echo form_error('emailconf'); ?><span>
    </div>
</div>
</br>    
</br>
<div class="form-group row">     
    <div class="col-md-2"> </div>      
    <div class=" col-sm-8" style="text-align: center;">
        <button type="button" id="submit" value="submit" class="btn btn-success" style="margin-left: 16px;" >Submit</button>
        <button type="reset"  id="reset" name="reset" type="reset" class="btn btn-warning">Reset</button>    
        <a href="<?php echo base_url() ?>form/login" class="btn btn-danger">Cancel</a>    
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2"> </div> 
</div>
</form>    

    <div class="col-sm-2"></div>
</div>    
</div>
</body>
</html>    
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
  $("#submit").click(function(){      
    $.ajax({
       url:"<?php echo site_url('form/new_user_registration') ?>",
       type: 'POST',
       data: $("#reg_form").serialize(),
       success: function(res){
           alert("Data inserted successfully ?");
           $("#reg_form").html(res);
           $('#username').val('');
           $('#password').val('');
           $('#passconf').val('');
           $('#email').val('');
           $('#emailconf').val('');  
       },           
       error: function(){
           alert("Fail")
       }
   });
   return false;
  });
});

$(document).on("click", "input[type='reset']", function(){
   $("select").trigger("change");
});

if($("#email").val() != $("#emailconf").val())
{
    alert("emails don't match");
}
</script>

Jquery script

$(document).ready(function(){
$('#reg_form').validate({
    rules: {
        email: 'required',
        emailConf: {
            equalTo: '#email'
        }
    }
}),
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#reg_form').validate({
rules: {
    email: 'required',
    emailconf: {
        equalTo: '#email'
    }
}
}),
```

Change `emailconf` instead of `emailConf`
and

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?--php echo $this->base_url();?>assets/js/validation.js"></script>
```

to

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo $this->base_url();?>assets/js/validation.js"></script>
```

Comment: I am using external Jquery but it is not working. I edited my code through your code. This is my external Jquery.   Data passing through AJAX properly.

Comment: Check your browser console did you get any issue?

Comment: Included JS `src="<?php echo $this->base_url();?>assets\/js/validation.js` change properly

Comment: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) ..... giving this error in console....... validation.js not found ... what i do for this??

Comment: Add Your validation.js file properly, check your file is available or not in the file path .